# Scrollview multiple LinearLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

So I have multiple linearlayouts (4) and I would like to have them all in a `scrollview`. These layouts are used for input fields that are separated by column/category `Names, Ages, Occupation, and Country of Residence`.

Each one of these has their own `linearlayout`. Is there a way to make them all scrollable simultaneously (since scrollview only supports 1 child)?

Answer (score 4):

Just have one `LinearLayout` that contains all other `LInearLayouts`

[From Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

> ... meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects

This means that it can have only one ***direct*** child (the main `LinearLayout`) but that one child can have its own children.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was possible, but I will give it a shot. With a simple addition of <LinearLayout> </LinearLayout> around all other layouts work?

Comment: Yep, I need 10 more characters, there they are ;)

Comment: When I add the tags around the other layouts, it crashes :(

Comment: You need to be more specific. What does the logcat say? Also, try cleaning first. "Project --> Clean..."

Comment: Okay, the problem is I don't know the exact length and width to wrap around the other layouts

Answer (score 2):

`ScrollView` can have only one direct child

so use one Layout that will Contain all your Layouts

**Like**

```
<ScrollView  .....>
<LinearLayout .....>

   .............Your All other Layouts .................

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes... thats the issue. How can I go about making them all scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take your time and do it one at a time. As Tarsem said, you can put one layout inside this scrollview

```
<ScrollView  .....>
<LinearLayout .....>
      //Inside this layout, you can another scroll view.
           <ScrollView  .....>
              <LinearLayout .....>

                       .............All your other Layouts .................
                     //continue adding them until you add your last scroll view.  if that 
                      is the desire layout.
                </LinearLayout>
             </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to work backwards? ie. I have my linear layouts already set, but I need to wrap them now with a linear layout

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView 
   <LinearLayout     // Your Main Layout 
       <LinearLayout   // Child Layout 1st
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout   // Child Layout 2nd
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout   // Child Layout 3rd
       </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Try to use about format.

Hope it helps.

Regards